# Elementary question on Dynkin system.

Tags: measure-theory

I have got a question while I am solving a problem.

Show that $B\setminus A$ is in a Dynkin system if $A$ and $B$ is in the Dynkin system.

I was trying to:

$B\setminus A=B\cap A^c=B\cap(A^c\cup B^c)=B\cap(A\cap B)^c\\
=\{B^c\cup(A\cap B)\}^c $

Thus, we can argue that it is in the system because $B^c$ and $A\cap B$ is disjoint. However, I was confused that how can I ensure $A\cap B$ is in the system since there is no finite intersection property. How can I draw this using the definition of Dynkin system? or Should I find another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is in general not true that a Dynkin system $\mathcal D$ is closed under set differences. Consider $X = \{1,2,3,4\}$ with the Dynkin system $\mathcal D = \{S \subseteq X \mid \#S \text{ is even}\}$. Then $\{1,2\},\{1,3\} \in \mathcal D$, but $\{2\} = \{1,2\} \setminus \{1,3\} \not \in \mathcal D$.

However, if $A \subseteq B$, your proof shows that $B \setminus A \in \mathcal D$, provided $A,B \in \mathcal D$ for any given Dynkin system $\mathcal D$.

Comment: Oh, I see the point. Thank you. BTW, you mean $\{2\}=\{1,2\}\setminus \{1,3\}\notin D$

Comment: @fblues Yes, obviously. I will correct that typo and blame my tiny keyboard ;-)